# Passing argument in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to get data from 2 tables with a LEFT JOIN having an unknow value.

I tried using LEFT JOIN but it didn't work.

Here is my code example :

```
SELECT 
    cc.shid,
    cc.user,
    ts.type,
    sum(cc.qty1) + sum(cc.qty2) as qty_tot,
    COUNT(cc.id) as nb
FROM
    content_c cc
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        s.shid,
        s.type
    FROM
        tab_s s
    LIMIT 1
    ) as ts ON ts.shid = cc.shid
WHERE 
    cc.time_i like '2019-01%'
GROUP BY 
    cc.user,
    ts.type
```

With that query it will never work : ts will contain the first occurence of tab_s regardless of cc.shid. I wonder if there is a way to make this :

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        s.shid,
        s.type
    FROM
        tab_s s
    WHERE
        s.shid = cc.shid
    LIMIT 1
    ) as ts ON ts.shid = cc.shid
```

Any idea ? Is there a pointer notion in SQL or something like ? Like I can use &cc.shid, or @cc.shid ?

Note that doing the following :

```
LEFT JOIN tab_s ts ON ts.shid = cc.shid
```

Will make my request to take more than 1 minute to display results. And I cannot set an index in tab_s.shid aswell as cc.shid as its have multiple occurences.

Please keep in mind that content_c can have multiple occurence of cc.shid, that why I need to take only the first result (LIMIT 1). It's important.

Comment: Indexes do not need to be unique. You can easily index `tab_s`.`shid`

Comment: It's hard to tell what youre trying to do from a query that doesn't work, but I imagin that you have eg Users and Addresses, and there can be multiple addresses but only the latest (as defined by some date) address is "current" so youre trying to get a list of users and their current address - and some users might not have any addresses recorded, hence you need a left join. Is this something near what you're trying to do? Please post a sample of the data in the tables

Comment: LIMIT 1 causes only one row total to be returned from the subquery, not one-row-per-id. What is the column that lets you determine whether a particular row in content_c is the first one? Like a min/max date or something. (Hopefully you wont say "oh, it can be any row, we just randomly write duplicate meaningless rows into content_c, and any singe one of them would be suitable to use in the query")

Comment: No that's not it. It's about articles & comment, and I want to produce some stats. You can see it like content_c = articles + comments & tab_s = type of article. I want to produce stats : For each user, display the number of comment, the number of article commented & per "type of article". Actually, showing up the number of comment work, the number of article commented also, but when I try to include the type of article (that will enter in ORDER BY), it didn't work. I'll try to post some data.

Comment: Your content table contains the articles and the comments on them? Erk.. I'll be interested to see this data structure, cos it feels like there's a need to separate those already

Comment: No it contains only the id of articles. I don't need more from articles, so I'm just using a COUNT on id to get the number of articles.

Comment: You have multiple entry in tab_s with same shid and same shid also tagged with same Type in column s.type.... and that's why you are looking for LIMIT 1 right?

Comment: That's right. But also note that I have multiple entry in content_c with same shid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cc.shid, cc.user, cc.type,
       SUM(cc.qty1) + SUM(cc.qty2) as qty_tot,
       COUNT(cc.id) as nb
FROM (SELECT cc.*,
             (SELECT s.type
              FROM tab_s s
              WHERE ts.shid = cc.shid
              LIMIT 1 
             ) as type
      FROM content_c cc
     ) cc
WHERE cc.time_i >= '2019-01-01' AND
      cc.time_i < '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY cc.shid, cc.user, cc.type;
```

Notes:

- The use of `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY` is suspicious.  Why would there be duplicates in the underlying table?
- Your date comparisons are bad.  **Use date/time functions when working with date/time values.**  Don't use string functions.
- The `GROUP BY` should include all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the question comments, Can you please try this  script and see if it meets your requirements? This will return a row per ID in "content_c" table with the GROUP BY impact.

```
SELECT 
    cc.shid,
    cc.user,
    ts.type,
    sum(cc.qty1) + sum(cc.qty2) as qty_tot,
    COUNT(cc.id) as nb
FROM content_c cc
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT s.shid, s.type FROM tab_s s
) AS ts ON ts.shid = cc.shid
WHERE cc.time_i like '2019-01%'
GROUP BY cc.shid,cc.user,ts.type
```